# Preventing script execution on ajax load pages with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a page using the load() function, the problem is that javascript code on that page is being executed when loading. I use this:

```
$('#itemid').load('thepage.php #selector', function() {
     MY CODE HERE
});
```

how can i prevent the javascript code from being executed and load only the HTML part that i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.get()` or `.post()` and process what you get back.  Pull the script tags out of your returned code before you append it to the page, or just pull out the code you want:

```
$.post('thepage.php', {
    data: myData
}, function(data) {
    var myHTML = $(data).not('script');
    $('#itemid').html(myHTML);
});
```

Or:

```
$.post('thepage.php', {
    data: myData
}, function(data) {
    var myHTML = $(data).filter('#selector');
    $('#itemid').html(myHTML);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/wpNBM/

**Note:** As you mentioned, using a selector with load should accomplish the same thing, as you see in the example.  So, if it isn't working this way, something else is going on.

Comment: i think that this is exactly what i need, i'll try it right now and report back the results. I forgot to mention that i'm not uusing jQuery exactly, but i'm using the Zepto script (that should work in same way for that functions). I'm thinking that it's a bug, cause reading the jQuery documentation for the load() function i've readed that scripts are executed ONLY if load is used WITHOUT using a selector from the loaded page... but in Zepto it's not working that way

Comment: Yes, the selector should work, like in my jsfiddle example.  I am not familiar with Zepto, but from what it sounds like the syntax is the same, but not all features are guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: From the Zepto docs: "Note that emulation of all features of jQuery is not a project goal".  They are most concerned with being a small library.  That means they give up some features to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the problem correctly, but you could remove the javascript and just have the html. I assume you want to js bindings to happen on the new page though. So when you load the new page, in the callback, you could call a function that applies the needed bindings.

```
function applyAfterAjax(){
  $(this).find('element').click(function(){alert('clicked');});
}
$('#itemid').load('thepage.php #selector',applyAfterAjax);
```