# $.ajax() GET looping after each click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying something new and that is to load every page with `$.ajax()`. Everything works fine except for one thing! When I click on a link many times (navigating), everything loops it self after each click. You can see what I mean here: /website/sort/scifi (I'll remove this link when I have accepted an answer). I am using `console.log()` for every click so bring up the console.

I have tried to see if it is the variable but it isn't. I made another page (same thing here - I'll remove this link when I have accepted an answer) in order to see if the same problem  occurred but it didn't.

```
// KLICK: Sortera efter genre
$('body').on('click', '#genre', function() {

    // VARIABEL
    genre = $(this).attr('data');

    // VISA
    $('.loading').show();

    // INNEHÅLL
    $('.loading-content').html('Laddar sidan - var god vänta');


    // AJAX
    $.ajax({

        // AJAX: Adress till filen som ska hämtas
        url: '<?php echo url("view-genre/' + genre + '"); ?>',

        // AJAX: Vilken metod ska användas (GET eller POST)
        method: 'GET',

        // AJAX: Lyckades
        success: function(s) {

            // ADRESS
            history.pushState('', document.title, '<?php echo url("sort/' + genre + '"); ?>');

            // DÖLJ
            $('.loading').hide();

            // INNEHÅLL
            $('#content').html(s);

            console.log(genre);

        },


        // AJAX: Misslyckades
        error: function(e) {

        }

    });

});
```

How can I prevent this bug?

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself, precisely because after you've removed the links this question has no benefit to anyone who might have the same problem.

Comment: Very true. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the file you're loading with Ajax contains the same JavaScript code as the main page. Every time the file is requested a new click handler is attached to the links, which effectively doubles the handlers on each click.

The solution then is to not include the script to the files that are loaded, or if that's not possible for some reason, make sure the script isn't executed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829131/preventing-script-execution-on-ajax-load-pages-with-jquery) for an example.)

Comment: Aha! I removed the JavaScript code from the requested file and now it works perfectly :) Sweet! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed a few things:

Your HTML link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="genre" data="scifi" title="Visa andra filmer och TV-serier med den här genren">SciFi</a>
```

Would ideally look like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0); return false;" id="genre" data="scifi" title="Visa andra filmer och TV-serier med den här genren">SciFi</a>
```

Or, you can achieve (roughly) the equivalent by doing it in js

```
$('body').on('click', '#genre', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Also, you should give scope to your 'genre' variable by defining it like this

```
var genre = $(this).attr('data');
```

Not positive these are causing the bug, but they don't help! :)

Cp

==== EDITED =====

Juhana has solved the bug :)

Comment: `return false` in the href attribute does nothing.